# Select distinct rows from a table using massive ORM

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, massive

How can I retrieve distinct rows from a table using massive ORM . I need to get list of unique studentname from table 'Student' that has columns ID,StudentName,Age . ID is the primary key.

Note : executing raw query using Query() is not what is needed.

Comment: If you aren't just looking for DISTINCT can you elaborate a little.

Comment: Im looking for distinct but i just cant find a way to execute 'distinct' using massive ORM other that Query() which i not what I need because it is very much similar to executing raw query without the use of any ORM

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002613/kohana-3-2-i-want-to-get-distinct-dates This talks about distinct form the right angle?

Comment: Thanks for the comment dude. But the link you provided mentions ORM in general . My scenario is specific for Massive ORM .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
dynamic studentTable = new Students();
var students = studentTable.All(columns: "distinct StudentName");
```

Answer (score 0):

create non-clustered index on studentname column and then try this query

```
select distinct StudentName from Student
```